# How to extract all buildings from `osm.pbf` file using command-line Osmosis?

Tags: osmosis

I'm using [Osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Beginner%27s_guide) 0.48 using command line on Windows to extract all building polygons from a given `osm.pbf` file downloaded from Geofabrik (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany.html). However, running the following query only obtains for results in an empty `multipolygon` layer:

```
osmosis --read-pbf "C:\osm\bayern-latest.osm.pbf" --tf accept-ways buildings=* --used-node --write-xml buildings.osm
```

Am I missing something in the query? How can I change the syntax to get all multipolygons in the output? I'm interested in all buildings (`Key=building` and all values).

Osmosis documentation:

[https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Beginner's_guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Beginner%27s_guide)
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.48

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution is to simply set `building=*` (instead of `buildings=*`). The rest of the command is correct and creates an `osm` file containing **all** buildings in the .pbf file.

```
osmosis --read-pbf "C:\BDProjects\Placesense\osm\bayern-latest.osm.pbf" --tf accept-ways building=* --used-node --write-xml C:\BDProjects\Placesense\geodata\building.osm
```